# List members of organisation belonging to sub-types

Tags: drupal-views

I have my organisation split between local sport clubs.
I'm looking for a best way to list all members of particular clubs - should I use Drupal Views or Civi search'es or reports?
Thnx
R.

Answer (score 2):

Searchkit looks like it can pull in related contact data

[Search view that shows the mutual relationships between two contacts](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/40990/search-view-that-shows-the-mutual-relationships-between-two-contacts)

There's a bit of a learning curve, but I found this overview from a recent CiviCRM meetup really helpful

https://youtu.be/-YJyRt02vvw

Answer (score 1):

Partly depends who needs to see the report but we tend to build all such results in Drupal Views.

Comment: Hi Pete,
Right now I want to list all members, which is fine, almost - my view doesn't show the club they are member of, even though they are in relationship with the club in their contact panel.
Also, I've got trouble building a filter to show a dropdown of all clubs so the list can be limited.
Thnx

Comment: using views 'relationships' you should be able to join to the required tables and get the required. v overdue reply. apologies